# Best way to record court appointed community service?

Tags: civievent, civivolunteer

Our charity is a source for court appointed community service. Those volunteers are normally assigned to activities in and around the office, like cleaning, moving boxes of food around for the food pantry, etc. I hate to call it this, but in a lot of cases it might just be busy work in order to satisfy the probation conditions.  In other words, it's probably not the type of event the original coders had in mind when developing this app.  I have been reading and watching everything I can about events and I cannot convince myself that that is the best approach to recording activity/task hours for these types of people.

If that's it, then I'll go with it and figure out the best configuration within the framework of that feature.

BTW, this is running on Drupal and I have CiviVolunteer installed and working.

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CiviVolunteer 2.0 (currently available in beta) allows you to assign volunteer time without tying it to an event.  This may solve your issue.  However, in your case, I think Xavier is right, and an activity should be sufficient if all you're trying to do is record time, not manage the volunteer process.

You can add a custom field to activities to indicate if time is court-appointed community service, so you can record all time the same way but easily segment it if need be.

Answer (score 2):

it might be easier to log these as activities.  you can create new activity types, eg community service.

if you need a more complete overview of the activities spent around a volunteer,eg not only being able to see the time they spent, but also the monitoring and helping tasks of others, or record court events, try civicase. more complete, but more complex to set up

Comment: Thanks, and that gives me something to think about.  CiviEvent was previously recommended (if only to consider), so I hadn't really thought about it this way.  But, I think I want to record all volunteer hours the same way, then somehow segment them out when I build the report. So does it still make sense to add volunteers who volunteer out of the kindness of their hearts to the same method as court appointed volunteers?  Thanks again- a bunch.  I am sold on this app generally...  I'll make it work, and knowing me, I will wind up helping other small NPs afterwards if they want to try Civi.

Comment: hey @S.Wilhite whereabouts are you based in the UK? Feel free to email at michael@civicrm.org - would be good to say hi and hear about how you are using CiviCRM.